# How am I supposed to move this text inside this div to bottom center?

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #bad455;
}

.basic {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    line-height: 30px;

    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 8px solid red;
}

.container {
}

.basic > p {
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="basic">
            <p>This text should move</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Further code... -->
</body>
```

Sorry but a stupid question. I'm not sure why this text doesn't go down 50% inside this `div`? I've been trying to use vertical-align, padding-top, text-center to 50%, but they didn't work that well and it always goes more than 50%. So is there any way to push this text inside to the center? Maybe its a position problem or something? I've been trying to solve this for quite a while but can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: [How to Center Elements Vertically and Horizontally in Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/1115360)?

Comment: If you want to center the text inside the DIV. Use flex :)

Comment: So many duplicates, please try doing a little search and research before posting a question

Comment: You've missed a curly bracket in your CSS